# Converter String Ex. 1.520,30 para um BigDecimal usando o @InitBinder do Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Tenho uma tela na qual trabalho com as mascaras de valor monetário do  *jQuery Mask*, quando o usuário realiza o *submit* do *form* o valor retornado para meu *controller* é **Ex:. 1.340,34.**

O atributo em meu *Bean* que é realizado o *bind* é um *BigDecimal*. Logo tive que criar um *CustomNumberEditor* e registra-lo em um *@InitBinder* como mostrado abaixo:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBigDecimalBinder(WebDataBinder binder) throws Exception {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    dfs.setGroupingSeparator('.');
    dfs.setDecimalSeparator(',');
    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(BigDecimal.class, new CustomNumberEditor(BigDecimal.class, df, true));
  }
```

O Maior problema é que os valores não ficam de forma correta, ou seja o numero de exemplo logo acima fica **1340** no banco de dados, sendo que o certo seria 1.340.34.

Como posso realizar tal conversão de forma correta?

Comment: João, sua dúvida me ajudou bastante, ajustando a precisão via anotação resolveu meu problema

Answer (score 3):

Com BigDecimal é interessante ter um método para setar a escala de arredondamento e a precisão do valor.

Caso estiver utilizando JPA para persistencia, uma forma simples de fazer isso é com a anotação @Column.

```
@Column(precision = 2, scale = 3)
private BigDecimal valor;
```

Outra forma é ter um método próprio para manipular o valor com a escala e precisão que deseja.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale-int-int-

Tenha certeza que a tabela no banco de dados tem o formato correto para adequar numeros decimais.

Comment: Tudo ok ao adicionar a escala.